# How to efficiently calculate cube roots using decimal in python

Tags: python, arbitrary-precision

I am quite new using the decimal module in python and I was wondering what is the most efficient method to calculate cube-roots (or any root really). I tried `num ** (Decimal(1)/Decimal(3)` but it took quite a while. For example, the code below takes about 20 seconds on an Intel i5 processor running python 3:

```
from decimal import *

getcontext().prec = 10000
a0 = Decimal(3.0)

import time
beg = time.time()
cuber = a0**(Decimal(1)/Decimal(3))
end = time.time()
print(end-beg)
```

I know something better can be done because just writing a simple newton algorithm gives much shorter run time (see code below).  **So, my question is what is a good method (built-in preferably) to take integer roots of decimals?**

The quick newton method, which is much faster (~0.2 seconds) is below:

```
def cube_root( A):
    guess = (A-Decimal(1))/Decimal(3)
    x0 = (Decimal(2) * guess + A / Decimal(guess*guess) )/Decimal(3.0)
    while 1:
        xn =(Decimal(2) * x0 + A / Decimal(x0*x0) )/Decimal(3.0)
        if xn == x0:
            break
        x0 = xn
    return xn

beg = time.time()
print(cuber - cube_root(a0))
end = time.time()
print(end-beg)
```

The sample output of all of the code above,on my system, is:

```
23.898984670639038
0E-9999
0.10790443420410156
```

Comment: Hm, seems like newton's wins! That make sense, I think that's how they implement `sqrt`.

Comment: They really should provide a `integer_root` function.

Comment: @juan.arrivillaga: What do you mean by integer_root?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga agreed, I shouldn't have to implement root algorithms when I want to do something as simple as taking an integer root.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque like x**(1/n) where n is an integer. So square-root, cubed root, etc

Comment: @jman yeah. At least this isn't Java, where you don't even have `sqrt` implemented, and forget about logarithms!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such a low-order cube root, Newton's is going to be your best bet.  I made the loop more efficient by removing the inner test, and got about a 5% speed improvement.  Removing redundant `Decimal` conversions got another 2-3%.

```
def cube_root( A): 
    d1 = Decimal(1)
    d2 = Decimal(2)
    d3 = Decimal(3)

    x0 = (A-d1)/d3
    xn = (d2 * x0 + A / Decimal(x0*x0) ) / d3

    while xn != x0:
        x0 = xn
        xn = (d2 * x0 + A / Decimal(x0*x0) ) / d3

    return xn
```